# jquery drag and drop tags many to one

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Im trying to implement many to one drag drop tagging as [jsfiddle.net/7683X/126/](http://jsfiddle.net/7683X/126/). Actually am getting the values of '.box' from database.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        galleryDragAndDrop("#test-container", "#gallery-one", "#gallery-two", "#gallery-three", ".box");

});
    function galleryDragAndDrop(mainContainer, containerOne, containerTwo, containerThree, dragItem) {
    $(dragItem).draggable(
        {              
            containment: mainContainer,
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move",
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.helper.prevObject).addClass("box_current");
            },                
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.helper.prevObject).removeClass("box_current");
            }                
        });

    $(containerTwo).droppable({

        accept: dragItem,
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            acceptBoxIngalleryTwo(ui.draggable);
        }

    });

    $(containerOne).droppable({
        accept:dragItem,
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            acceptBoxIngalleryOne(ui.draggable);

        }

    });

    $(containerThree).droppable({
        accept: dragItem,
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            acceptBoxIngalleryThree(ui.draggable);

        }

    });

    function acceptBoxIngalleryTwo(item) {
        $(item).fadeOut(function () {
            $(containerTwo).append(item);
        });
       $(item).fadeIn();
        $(item).removeClass("box_current");
    }

    function acceptBoxIngalleryOne(item) {
        $(item).fadeOut(function () {
            $(containerOne).append(item);
        });

        $(item).fadeIn();
        $(item).removeClass("box_current");
    }

    function acceptBoxIngalleryThree(item) {
        $(item).fadeOut(function () {
            $(containerThree).append(item);
        });

        $(item).fadeIn();
        $(item).removeClass("box_current");
    }
}
```

What i need is i have 3 div as gallery-one(source1),gallery-two(target),gallery-three(source2). I drag elements from source1 and source2 to target. When i drag those elements back to source divs from target div, it must check that dragged element was previously from source1 or source2 in such a way that source1 should not accept the tag from source2 and so. Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fiddle is not working.

Comment: sorry, i have updated the link. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Did you try this? http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: @vel Thanks for the reply.But still I cannot get the solution. Am new to jquery. Can you please give me an example ?

Comment: Did you look that link?

Comment: Yes. But i am so confused. Trying.

Comment: I did like this not exactly. Its takes some times for me.

Comment: Also any idea how i can save those tags in database??(i have saved the tag value to a variable in jquery. How i can pass this to the <input> tag)

Comment: There is no <input> tag in code. can you brief?

Comment: Am asking is there any way i can pass these tag values i have saved as variables in script to "Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Tags)". If no, how can i save these tag values. Can you plz give any idea.

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea